# MySql Functions: Convert VARCHAR to actual tablename to use in a SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, function

How do I use function parameters in an actual SELECT Statement Ex:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDefaultLangText(tableName VARCHAR(50), fieldName VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(200) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN  
Select fieldName from tableName
END
```

This doesn't work it tells me that tableName doesn't exist which is true of course but what I really want is to plugin the actual value in the variable tableName (and also fieldName)

Comment: This function is not very helpful. You can do the same thing using any form of programming language to construct the actual SQL to be executed.Can show us what stopped you?

Comment: Yes I'm using this just as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in MySQL must be prefixed with `@`, otherwise they're seen as raw field/table names, so...

```
SELECT @fieldName FROM @tableName
```

however, this syntax isn't allowed. fieldnames and tablenames cannot be inserted into a query via variables in this manner: [MySQL Stored Procedure dynamic change name of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662850/mysql-stored-procedure-dynamic-change-name-of-table). So changing your query statement will not fix the greater problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar has been posted awhile back: [use a variable for table name in mysql sproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754423/use-a-variable-for-table-name-in-mysql-sproc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql like:

PREPARE stmt FROM @sqltext;
EXECUTE stmt USING @temptable;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

The sqltext is a string which can contain the query

Comment: Dynamic SQL isn't allowed in functions